# $cordovaFileTransfer.download Permission Error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a mobile app (using ionic/cordova) that is downloading an mp4 file.  I made it work in android, but no luck doing in iOS.  Weird thing is that, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (only in iOS).  I used the plugin `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` when it works, it works perfectly.  But when I alert the error, I get the  following:

> Could not create path to save downloaded file: You don't hvae permission to save the file
>   Error code: 1

Here's my following code:

```
$scope.download = function(){

        var downloadProgress ='';
        var url = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4";
        var MyFiles = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'test1.mp4';
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url,MyFiles,{}, true).then(
            function(result){//success download

                $ionicLoading.hide();
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Download Successful!',
                });


            }, function(error){
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                                        title: 'Error',
                                        template: JSON.stringify(error)
                                    });
            }, function(progress){
                            $timeout(function () {
                                downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                            });

                            $ionicLoading.show({
                                template: 'Download in progress please wait<br/><progress id="progressbar" max="100" value="'+ downloadProgress +'"> </progress>' +
                                '<div id="progressbarlabel">' + Math.ceil(downloadProgress) + '%</div>'
                                    });
                });  

    }
```

Comment: may be use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory for the location to store the images in the device

Comment: nah I already used all of the directory

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` in iOS this:

```
if (ionic.Platform.isIPad() || ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            console.log("Is iPad or iOS");
            $rootScope.TARGETPATH = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;;
        }
```

And the result in the Emulator was very well, but when I tried in a real device I get:

> You don’t have permission to save the file “Documents” in the folder “MY-APP-ID-XXXXXX”.

so, I tried with `cordova.file.dataDirectory`:

```
if (ionic.Platform.isIPad() || ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            console.log("Is iPad or iOS");
            $rootScope.TARGETPATH = cordova.file.dataDirectory;;
        }
```